# Horizontal scroll-bar issue

Tags: html, css

I've set `width` to 100% for all main divs but there is still horizontal scroll-bar. Can't fix that problem. How to remove it? I don't know why it's appearing. Please take a look at my test page.  http://aquastyle.az?lang=en

Comment: Your test page is not opening.  Please fix it or post some code and/or a fiddle.

Comment: That's a tremendous amount of code to dig through.  Perhaps you could post just the relevant portions in your question.

Comment: If you want "help", you have to be willing to put some effort into posting your question.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/36tvl take a look at the screenshot. Do you see adress bar? The js detects height and width and sends it to php. And do you see scrollbar?

Comment: Yes, the content is the same when the window is opened in every browser.  And there is a horizontal scroll-bar because there is too much side-by-side content to fit in the window.  When I make the window about 1700 pixels wide, the horizontal scroll-bar goes away because then everything "fits" in the window.

Comment: there are 3 columns side by side within the container. you think it's "too much"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3760/discussion-between-l0rd-devdem0rt-and-sparky672)

Comment: **Quote:**  _"there are 3 columns side by side within the container. you think it's 'too much'?"_  Answer:  Yes, when the center column alone is wider than most people's monitors!

Comment: listen, it fit's automatically to your display resolution. php code calculates it.

Comment: Listen, it's not working very well if it calculate the user's "display" width while the user's "browser window" is much narrower.  **Display** width is not equal to **Browser Window** width.  Think about it.

Comment: check out my page to see how i did it.

Comment: It's not looking too good...  It's still calculating my computer's display width (1680 px) even when my browser's window width is only about 1000 px wide.  Your horizontal scroll-bar is gone but the third column is on top of the second column and there is a short horizontal scroll-bar on just the six buttons in the bottom of the center column.  Can't you see/test this for yourself by opening in a browser window narrower than your LCD display?

Comment: I don't think you understand what I've been trying to tell you... not everybody is going to have their browser window open to the full width of their computer screen.  Your php is constructing a page 1680 pixels wide for a browser window that is some arbitrary value **LESS THAN** 1680 pixels wide.  Your php needs to construct the page based upon the width of the browser window and **not** the width of the display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot get your test page to open but this is typically caused when you have padding, a shadow, or a border applied to the 100% width element causing it to render wider than 100%.

Without seeing the page, I can only give the following generic advice:  This can be fixed by removing the style properties that are causing the problem or reducing the width until the problem disappears.

**EDIT:**

After looking at your page, you don't seem to have a problem as you described.  You just have  too much (too big/wide) content side by side.  When I make my browser's window about 1700 pixels wide, the horizontal scroll-bar disappears.  This is an issue of poor layout more than programming.

**EDIT 2 (The Root Cause/Solution):**

It seems that the OP's PHP program is calculating the "display" width and placing content accordingly.    The problem is that the "browser window" width is not the same as the "display" width.  My display is 1680 pixels wide and the OP's PHP program reports that correctly.  Naturally, my browser window is not 1680 pixels wide, more like 1000-1200 pixels, so I get a long horizontal scroll-bar which disappears when I make the browser window exceed 1680 pixels.  Taking the width of the vertical scroll-bar into account, you actually have to make the browser window about 20 pixels wider than the display in order to get the horizontal scroll-bar to disappear (for me that was about 1700 pixels total).  I imagine the OP can fix this issue by looking at browser's "viewport" (window) width rather than the computer's "display" width.

Comment: @L0rdDEVdem0rt, commenting should be kept to a minimum and on-topic.

Comment: which browser are you using? there is the js that gets width and height and sends it to php.

Comment: @L0rdDEVdem0rt, I'm seeing the same thing in Mozilla and Webkit browsers.  There is no horizontal scroll-bar if the user can make his window about 1700 pixels wide.

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works... questions/answers/comments are supposed to benefit everyone.  (My screenshot would look just like the one you posted.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3761/discussion-between-l0rd-devdem0rt-and-sparky672)

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use

```
overflow:hidden
```

on the element you're trying to eliminate the scroll bars from.

Or, you could use jQuery:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

**EDIT:**

Your layout is 1920x1200.  I have that resolution right now and I NEVER max out my browser window.  It's always 20 to 25% smaller.

Most if not 98% of website layouts are 960px max width.  I looked at your CSS (nice try with disabling right-click BTW) and you're left and right columns are both 200px EACH, while your main-content width is 1460px.  I think you see where I'm going with this.  I'm sorry, but the only way you're going to get no scrollbars is to redo your layout where everything fits in a 1000px layout or less. Preferably less.  An important thing to check is the screen resolution stats that help in determining what percentage of users is running at a certain screen resolution.  This will help you in targeting your preferred audience.

**TL;DR**

You gotta redo your entire layout, it's too wide for the majority of users out there..

Comment: Don't you see your address bar? JS file gets your current reolution and send it to php file. Php calculates entire css widths and heights with your resolution. Is it clear?

Comment: +1 to counter-act the OP's down-vote.  Your answer exemplifies the problem but see my EDIT #2 for the explanation.

Comment: I think its the issue with max-width. I have similar issue and I have set the 'max-width' of the body to 1310px to resolve the issue. But I don't know the exact concept.